# ImageView with address from variable

Tags: android, imageview

This is a part of my .xml code:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/param"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="paramText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/this_is_my_image" />
```

TextView displays the text located in the "paramText" ie "hello" by using this part of a code:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chart_fragment, container, false);;
    TextView paramView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.param);
    paramView.setText(paramText);

    return view;
}
```

My ImageView shows the defined image located in mipmap named "this_is_my_image".
What I want is to load the image with the exact name which is located in the paramText variable. So, in my example I would like to load image with the name "hello" located in the mipmap.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
        //paramText is name of your drawable
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(paramText, "mipmap", 
           context.getPackageName());
       ImageView imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 imageview.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: I put your code inside onCreateView... just above return view, and "Resources", "context", "getIdentifier" and "imageview" are all marked red. Excuse me, I am a newbie in Android studio. "cannot find symbol class Resources", "Cannot find symbol variable context", "cannot find symbol variable imageview"

Comment: I changed "drawable" into "mipmap" since images are located there and now I get the error: cannot ind symbol variable imageview

Comment: you have to get your imageview with `findViewById(R.id.imageView)` like you are getting your textview

Comment: you mean like this?

Comment: Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.param);
        final int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(paramText, "mipmap", getContext().getPackageName());
        myImageView.setImageResource(resourceId);

Comment: Solved! With some tweaking of Masoud Mokhtari code. First, "Resources" class was unknown and I pressed Alt+Enter and it wasn't unknown anymore. Second, I changed "drawable" into "mipmap" since my pictures are located in the mipmap, and it solved my problem. Thanks a lot to everyone who gave their suggestions.

Comment: If my answer is useful for you, please set my answer as correct answer and give me an vote up. thanks ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
Resources resources = getContext().getResources(); // paramText is name of your drawable 
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(paramText, "drawable", context.getPackageName()); 
imageview.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.